# Log File of apache tomcat server

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

i am new in java, To see any exception which throw by java code we have to see log file of Tomcat server . How Apache tomcat server is responsible for maintain log for java code??

Answer (score 2):

In Tomcat Apache's Java **Commons Logging (JCL)** technology is used throughout Tomcat.  JCL is a lightweight API for Java applications that allows hierarchical logging to be supported across all log levels, independent of logging implementation.  This means that rather being limited to a specific hard-coded framework, you can choose the solution that works for you with only a small amount of extra configuration.   you can also use **java.util.logging framework.** . And any java code your programs throw Tom cat check for exception type and put it in logs file for more detail you can [check here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

Install folder>apache>tomcat>logs> here you can find logfiles

Comment: i am  asking about  how tomcat trace log for Java Code

Comment: You asking about internal structure of tomcat for log?
Am i right?

Comment: yes i am asking about internal structure of tomacat for log that responsible to  store Runtime exception throw by Java Code

Answer (score 0):

Every Tracelog from exceptions that is thrown from your application is put into apache/tomcat/logs.